# NSNull integerValue: Unrecognized Selector - Flutter IOS only

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, pthreads, nsexception

### TL;DR

I am getting an error only on IOS physical device when tapping certain buttons that excecute a certain line of code. I need to interpret the error and find the cause (why only on physical device?)

---

I am getting this error:

> -[NSNull integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2069e0558
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull integerValue]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2069e0558'
> *** First throw call stack: (0x1ac9d1288 0x1c5701744 0x1acaaefc0 0x1ac965e98 0x1ac964f70 0x102e9aff0 0x106b80b14 0x10666ba8c
> 0x1ac636e6c 0x1ac638a30 0x1ac646f48 0x1ac646b98 0x1ac989800
> 0x1ac943704 0x1ac956bc8 0x1c8ac2374 0x1af2cab58 0x1af04c090
> 0x10265d384 0x102cb1da4) libc++abi: terminating with uncaught
> exception of type NSException
>
> - thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
>   frame #0: 0x00000001e4474b38 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
>   ->  0x1e4474b38 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1e4474b58               ; <+40>
>   0x1e4474b3c <+12>: pacibsp
>   0x1e4474b40 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
>   0x1e4474b44 <+20>: mov    x29, sp Target 0: (Runner) stopped.

Whenever I excecute the following Provider code on the tap of a button:

```
List<FrediUser>? allFrediUsers = Provider.of<List<FrediUser>>(context);
```

The actual code seems to have nothing to do with the error, it just triggers it.

### Important Notes

- This behaviour ONLY HAPPENS ON iPhone PHYSICAL DEVICE.
- Works in iPad PHYSICAL DEVICE.
- **IOS SIMULATOR** works as expected
- Works perfectly on **android** --> This means that there is no error with the provider package nor the code that is looking for that list.

I just need to interpret the error to know what it is exactly! All help wanted!

Comment: Can you share more code for the button tap callback?

Comment: It’s a simple gesture detector which pushes a stateful widget screen, that runs that one of code inside the build method. I will share code as soon as possible. I think the problem is device specific and nothing to do with any code.